# Why do fetch errors not have a stacktrace in my single page application?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, error-handling, stack-trace, fetch-api

I have two simple wrappers that handle requests in my single page application. One wraps [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) and throws an error if a response is not ok (not in the 200-300 range):

```
const fetchy = (...args) =>
  fetch(...args).then(response => {
    if (response.ok) {
      return response
    }

    throw new Error(response.statusText)
  })

export default fetchy
```

And one wraps fetchy and is used for GET requests:

```
const get = endpoint => {
  const headers = new Headers({ Authorization: `Bearer ${TOKEN}` })
  const init = { method: 'GET', headers }

  return fetchy(endpoint, init)
}
```

Now I'm using them in an action like so (this is a [redux-thunk](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk) action creator) :

```
export const fetchArticles = () => dispatch => {
  dispatch({ type: types.FETCH_ARTICLES })

  return get(endpoints.ARTICLES)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => normalize(data.items, [schemas.articles]))
    .then(normalized => dispatch(fetchArticlesSuccess(normalized)))
    // fetch errors caught here do not have error.stack
    .catch(error => dispatch(fetchArticlesFail(error)))
}
```

So I'm catching both errors in fetch itself (network errors), and errors returned from the `fetchy` wrapper (api errors). The problem is that network errors from fetch, caught in fetchArticles, do not contain a stack trace. So `error.stack` does not exist. Which is messing up my error reporting.

It is a valid error, and `error instanceof Error === true` and `error.message === 'Failed to fetch'`. So why does this error not have a stack trace? How can I fix it? It seems like maybe I could add an error callback to fetchy and re-throw any errors there, but that seems weird to me (but maybe I'm wrong).

Comment: So apparently error.stack is non-standard: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error/stack. However, since the error was thrown in a browser (Chrome 57) that supports error.stack it seems weird that fetch doesn't have a stacktrace. Does it not use the same Error constructor?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The fetch error is created asynchronously & not directly related to a particular line of JavaScript. Although I agree it would be helpful if the line of the fetch call was included. I've filed a bug for this https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=718760

As a workaround, you could catch the fetch error, and throw a new error if there are no numbers in the stack:

```
function fetchy(...args) {
  return fetch(...args).catch(err => {
    if (!err.stack.match(/\d/)) throw TypeError(err.message);
    throw err;
  }).then(response => {
    if (response.ok) return response;
    throw Error(response.statusText);
  });
}
```

Here's an example of that running http://jsbin.com/qijabi/edit?js,console

Comment: Thanks for filing the bug report. Also nice workaround, I had a similar fix, but with `.catch` at the end of the chain, which isn't as efficient as your fix. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, catch at the end would work too, but having it as close to the fetch as possible means it'll give you a line number closer to the one you're after.

Answer (score 5):

Recently I faced the same error. Production channel logged this error for about 500 times in just 2 months and it really got irritating. Ours’ is a rails application with frontend powered by react.

Here is what was happening in our case. When the page loads, the refresh button changes to cross button, now if some api request is in progress during this page loading time and the user click this cross button, then chrome browser throws this error. For the same situation Firefox throws NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.This is not really an issue which we should be worried about, and so we decided to make sentry ignore this error by using the ignoreErrors attribute of sentry.

```
Sentry.init({
  dsn: "sentry_dsn",
  ignoreErrors: [
    'TypeError: Failed to fetch',
    'TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.'
  ],
});
```

**Note:**
Failed to fetch is also generated by **CORS** errors, please be mindful of that too.
Also we decided to ignore errors with statusCode in between 400 to 426 using the beforeSend callback of sentry.

I spent days trying to find this error. Hope this helps somebody.

Originally I wrote this response on this page - https://forum.sentry.io/t/typeerror-failed-to-fetch-reported-over-and-overe/8447/2

Thank you